# Users are not adding to collections when registering

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on an express project but when I add register a user it gives me a 404 error on my website and nothing shows in the console and when I look up my collections it only make an session collection but not a collection  for users any help?
github link: https://github.com/JaniniRami/GameHelp
Schema is in the models, user.js
*I have a public folder but it wouldn't let me publish it to git hub because its more that 100 files so its not the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app.js yo have declared route as `app.use('/users', usersRouter);` but in form action you have mentioned as `<form class="form" action="/user/register" method="post">`. There is a mismatch on the route name. So you need to change the route name either on the `app.js` or form action in view file

```
//Quick Fix
app.use('/user', usersRouter);
```